# How does $(window).one('load') work, and how does it fail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As some background, I am working on building a web slider activity that fits into/extends another piece of software that outputs HTML. The key point being I have very little to no control over how the software outputs it's HTML Elements, but I can add arbitrary JavaScript and HTML elements on top of what the software outputs.

What I am trying to do is delay the loading of some images that I want to add until after all the software's outputted elements are loaded. So far I have it working by waiting to load the images until after the window load event is fired. Like so:

```
//-----Simplified example-----
$(document).on('ready', funciton(){
    //Some stuff to set things up
    $(window).one('load', function(){
        $('#SomeDiv').append('
            <img class= "someClass" 
            id="arbitraryImage1"
            src="folder/image1.jpg"
        ');
    });
});
```

Though it is working right now I'm not sure what will happen if something goes wrong. The HTML outputted by the software has a bad habit of including things that it might not need as well as occasionally not loading images on slower connections. The majority of the time if it does fail the user will not notice, so it isn't an issue. However I would like to know how `$(window).one('load', function(){})`behaves when a problem arises, so that I can work around the error or at least make the activity fail graciously. Any assistance or links to documentation would be appreciated, the generic-ness of 'window' and 'load' brings up a lot of irrelevant information when googling.

To summarize:

**What is the behaviour of `$(window).one('load', function(){})` when the window fails to load a resource (image, css, etc.)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. The documentation says:

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

But in practice, you'll find that the load event fires after all assets queued to load when the document was originally parsed (stylesheets, external scripts, img tags) have loaded, or failed loading. **As long as no requests are still pending**, the fact that these assets have loaded successfully or not has no bearing on the load event being fired.

The documentation is in need of a clarification, in my opinion, as it doesn't address your question.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now, I thought I just wasn't looking in the right places. Even though I am technically using jQuery's `$(window).one('load', function(){....` I assume it is functionally identical to vanilla JavaScript's `window.onload = function(){....`

Comment: @Malco - The functionality is identical. You also don't have to worry about using `.one` - the `load` event on the `window` object will never be fired more than once per page load. Although, `.on('load',function() { })` is more equivalent to `window.addEventListener('load',function() { })` than `window.onload = ...`, as it allows you to bind more than one function to the `load` event.

Answer (score 1):

If image fails to load, then there will be just no image in your image, if it will be unable to find SomeDiv, then nothing will be appended anywhere, generally if javascript function fails to some reasons - then nothing bad will happen, just broken functionality won't work, meaning load will still be done, just console will be telling about errors

Comment: I found web being very comfortable in these things, as everything that works will still work upon some fails in other parts :)

Comment: So you are saying that under the current setup if one of the resources fails to load, none of the new Images will be appended. Does the window not report any errors or things failing to load at all then? Do you have any links to documentation or is this just from experience?

Comment: As I see you are appending string values, it will still be appended if SomeDiv exists, just those images that haven't been loaded will be broken and all that have will be just fine. It's from my experience and from the actual things that happens in html, when you point image src to invalid path - there will be no image in that element

Comment: Your images won't be appended only if there are no elements with SomeDiv id, and to check that you can use $("#SomeDiv").length != 0

Comment: So does `$(window).one('load', function(){...` even do anything in the above instance then? I thought it was delaying appending the new images (into #SomeDiv) until after everything else on the page has loaded, but it seems that might not be true?

Comment: No, you are right, unless page is loaded it won't be executed, but failing to load images doesn't mean that page failed to load, it have loaded, just with some errors.

Comment: Ahh ok, this makes sense to me now.